# Upload file selected but not uploaded selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

I was trying to fill this file upload using selenium python but the fill was selected but not uploaded..

```
<div role="presentation" id="_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1a0b2c" class="wc-fieldlayout wc-layout-flat">
    <div id="_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1a0b2c0" class="wc-field"><span id="_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1a0b2c0a" class="wc-label"
            data-wc-for="_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1a0b2c0b" aria-hidden="true">File names<i aria-hidden="true"
                class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></span>
        <div class="wc-input">
            <fieldset id="_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1a0b2c0b" data-wc-cols="0" class="wc-multifileupload wc_noborder"
                aria-controls="_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1">
                <legend class="wc-moved-label">File names<i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></legend>
                <label class="wc-off" for="_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1a0b2c0b_input">file selector</label><input
                    id="_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1a0b2c0b_input" type="file" name="_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1a0b2c0b" multiple="multiple"
                    data-dropzone="_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1a0b2c0b"
                    accept="image/png,image/jpeg,application/pdf,image/bmp,image/gif,image/pjpeg"
                    data-wc-maxfilesize="5000000" data-wc-maxfiles="1">
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code:

```
ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@type="file"]')
ele.send_keys('/Users/Download/passport.jpg')
```

I have also tried:

```
    ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@type="file"]')
    ele.send_keys('/Users/Download/passport.jpg')
    time.sleep(2)
    ele.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVKNv.png)

Manual Upload:
[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RG0J.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below ways

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@type="file"]')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(ele).click().send_keys('/Users/Download/passport.jpg').perform()
```

***OR***

```
ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@type="file"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '/Users/Download/passport.jpg')", ele)
```

***OR***

```
driver.find_element_by_id('_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1a0b2c0b').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id('_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1a0b2c0a').send_keys('/Users/Download/passport.jpg')
driver.find_element_by_id('_2a0ca3b0a0a3a1a1a0b2c0a').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```